# SWT Browser internal link not working with IE6

Tags: java, browser, swt, eclipse-rcp, internet-explorer-6

In my Eclipse RCP Application, I am using SWT Browser to display HTML. I am displaying the HTML using `setText()` method. When tested on WinXP with Internet Explorer 6, I found that the inter links are not working and it simply displays **about:blank#4**. The about:blank is the name of the file and #4 is the link address where it had to jump. But its not working with IE 6...

This application works fine with Internet Explorer 7 and above. Any suggestions..??

Comment: Have you tried to open it direct from the IE6? And can you provide us the html code?

Comment: @aphex- I am sending the HTML Code directly using the `setText()` method. Same way works correctly with IE7 or greater.

Comment: IE6 is over 10 years old and has not been updated in ages. I would not be surprised if its just not supported anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327786) in `SWTBrowser`. However it is closed and they won't fix it, because it works with IE7 and IE8. Based on the [discussion](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=632884) it works however when you save it as file and call `setURL()`